# belongsTo relationship of two models data in extjs cannot display on grid panel

Tags: extjs4, relationship, belongs-to

I am using extJS for frontend and yii for backend. I have two models as Abodeinstitute ,AbodeInstituteContact. 
AbodeInstituteContact is a model which has 'instituteId' as a foreign key of Abodeinstitute table and I want to display 'instituteName' field of Abodeinstitute table, on grid with belongsTo relationship. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance...

//This is view code
Here instituteNames is the name of association used in model

```
   Ext.define('Balaee.view.abode.abodeinstitutecontact.AbodeInstituteContact',{
            extend:'Ext.grid.Panel',

            alias:'widget.abodeContactData',
            autoShow:true,
            store:'abode.abodeinstitutecontactStore',

            initComponent:function()
                {
                    this.columns=[
                                  {header:'ContactId', dataIndex:'contactId', flex:1},
                                  {header:'InstituteName', dataIndex:'instituteName', flex:1,

                                         renderer:function(val,data,record){
                                              var data='';
                                              record.instituteNames().each(function(Record){
                                                  data = data + Record.get('instituteName');
                                              });
                                              return data;
                                          }
                                     },
                                  {header:'InstituteId', dataIndex:'instituteId', flex:1},
                                  {header:'FirstName', dataIndex:'firstName', flex:1},
                                  {header:'MiddleName', dataIndex:'middleName', flex:1},
                                  {header:'LastName', dataIndex:'lastName', flex:1},

                                  {header:'ContactNo', dataIndex:'contactNo', flex:1},
                                  {header:'Email', dataIndex:'email', flex:1},
                                  {header:'DesignationId', dataIndex:'designationId', flex:1}
                             ],
                     this.callParent(arguments);
                }
        });
```

//The model code...

AbodeInstitute model has primary key 'instituteId'.

```
Ext.define('Balaee.model.abode.abodeinstituteModel',{
      extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
      idProperty:'instituteId',
      fields: ['instituteId','instituteName','instituteCategoryId'],

        associations:[
            {type:'HasMany',    model:'Balaee.model.abode.abodeinstitutecontactModel', foreignKey:'instituteId'}
        ],
});
```

AbodeInstituteContact 'instituteId' is a foreign key.

```
    Ext.define('Balaee.model.abode.abodeinstitutecontactModel',{
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        idProperty:'contactId',
        fields: ['contactId','instituteId','firstName','middleName','lastName','contactNo','email','designationId'],
     associations:[
        {type:'BelongsTo',  model:'Balaee.model.abode.abodeinstituteModel',
         name:'instituteNames'}],
     proxy:
        {
            type:'ajax',
            api:
            {
                read:
                create:
                update:
                destroy:
            },//End of api 
            reader:
            {
                type:'json',
                root:'abodeContactData',
                successProperty:true,
            },//End of reader
        }//End of proxy
    });
```

//json code

```
{
        "abodeContactData": [
            {
                "contactId": "4",
                "instituteId": "1",
                "instituteNames": [
                    {
                        "instituteName": "Balaee Pvt.LLP"
                    }
                ],
                "firstName": "Puja",
                "middleName": "Suresh",
                "lastName": "More",
                "contactNo": "32122323",
                "email": "puja@yahoo.com",
                "designationId": "3"
            },
            {
                "contactId": "6",
                "instituteId": "7",
                "instituteNames": [
                    {
                        "instituteName": "Soft"
                    }
                ],
                "firstName": "Riya",
                "middleName": "Ganesh",
                "lastName": "Mahajan",
                "contactNo": "23435",
                "email": "riya@gmail.com",
                "designationId": "2"
            },
            {
                "contactId": "12",
                "instituteId": "8",
                "instituteNames": [
                    {
                        "instituteName": "MST"
                    }
                ],
                "firstName": "Purva",
                "middleName": "Madhav",
                "lastName": "Patil",
                "contactNo": "98653210",
                "email": "purva@gmail.com",
                "designationId": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is backwards. You need to have your main model hasMany pointed at your Balaee.model.abode.abodeinstituteModel.  Also, I cleaned up your renderer as this is more appropriate and will give you a comma separated list in your grid within that column.

```
Ext.define('Balaee.model.abode.abodeinstituteModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty:'instituteId',
    fields: ['instituteId','instituteName','instituteCategoryId'],
    belongsTo: 'Balaee.model.abode.abodeinstitutecontactModel'
});

Ext.define('Balaee.model.abode.abodeinstitutecontactModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty:'contactId',
    fields: ['contactId','instituteId','firstName','middleName',
             'lastName','contactNo','email','designationId'],
    hasMany: [ 
        { model: 'Balaee.model.abode.abodeinstituteModel', 
          name: 'instituteNames', associationKey: 'instituteNames'}
    ],
    proxy: {
        type:'ajax',
        url: '/yoururl',
        reader: {
            type:'json',
            root:'abodeContactData'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('Balaee.view.abode.abodeinstitutecontact.AbodeInstituteContact',{
    extend:'Ext.grid.Panel',
    id: 'grid',
    alias:'widget.abodeContactData',
    autoShow:true,
    store: Ext.create('Balaee.store.abode.abodeinstitutecontactStore'),
    initComponent: function() {
        this.columns=[
            {header:'ContactId', dataIndex:'contactId', flex:1},
            {header:'InstituteName', dataIndex:'instituteName', flex:1,
                renderer:function(val,data,record){
                    var names = [];
                    record.instituteNames().each(function(Record){
                        names.push(Record.get('instituteName'));
                    });
                    return Ext.isEmpty(names) == false ? names.join(', ') : '';
                }
            },
            {header:'InstituteId', dataIndex:'instituteId', flex:1},
            {header:'FirstName', dataIndex:'firstName', flex:1},
            {header:'MiddleName', dataIndex:'middleName', flex:1},
            {header:'LastName', dataIndex:'lastName', flex:1},
            {header:'ContactNo', dataIndex:'contactNo', flex:1},
            {header:'Email', dataIndex:'email', flex:1},
            {header:'DesignationId', dataIndex:'designationId', flex:1}
         ],
         this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```